# How to view Javascript documentation from console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, documentation

Often when I'm working in Python, I'll quickly query what a function does in the iPython console by entering something like `dir??` which will return to me the documentation for `dir`. Is there a similar technique in Javascript? Whether this is in the terminal window or within the Chrome console?

Comment: There's nothing built in to the console, but I'd bet that there are browser extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely better off using Google and checking http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference to reference what functions do what.

Chrome console will give you functions you have available to your object, etc. but it won't tell you what does what.